# Using Reachability in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reachability

I'm trying to implement reachability in Swift, I have it running in Swift but something is different. I can't seem to be able to do the block syntax that works in objc-c for checking the network connection:

```
Reachable.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
            NSLog(@"connection reached");

    };
```

I can't get this to work in swift, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713449/using-apples-reachability-to-check-remote-server-reachability-in-swift

Comment: This might be of use… https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Answer (score 1):

```
        Reachable.reachableBlock = {(reach:Reachability!) -> Void in
             println("connection reached")
        }
```

That's how you write blocks in Swift..