# Using Apple's reachability class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am rewriting my existing Objective-C code (iOS) to [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) and now am facing some issues with the `Reachability` class of Apple for checking network availability... In my existing code I am using the following for achieving that.

```
var reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
var internetStatus:NetworkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {
    //my web-dependent code
}
else {
    //There-is-no-connection warning
}
```

And I am getting this error: `network status is not convertible to string`  at this line:

```
if (internetStatus != NotReachable)
```

Is there a method or class for getting network status?

I need these three conditions:

```
NotReachable: Obviously, there’s no Internet connection
ReachableViaWiFi: Wi-Fi connection
ReachableViaWWAN: 3G or 4G connection
```

Comment: This might be of use… https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: I added a more complete answer here I think : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787876/210456

Comment: http://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift now has CocoaPod support

Comment: Now there seems no error in this line: `if (internetStatus != NotReachable)`

Comment: Question subject is misleading. Reachability is not apple api.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For network availability (works in Swift 2):

```
class func hasConnectivity() -> Bool {
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus: Int = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().rawValue
    return networkStatus != 0
}
```

For a Wi-Fi connection:

```
(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == ReachableViaWiFi.value)
```

Comment: **let networkStatus: Int = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().rawValue** NOT **let networkStatus: Int = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value**

Comment: what is the header to import?

Comment: "import ReachabilitySwift" and download from https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift or using cocapods

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 let connected: Bool = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection().isReachable()

        if connected == true {
             println("Internet connection OK")
        }
        else
        {
            println("Internet connection FAILED")
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in to your appDelegate for checking reachability .

```
//MARK: reachability class
func checkNetworkStatus() -> Bool {
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().rawValue;
    var isAvailable  = false;

    switch networkStatus {
    case (NotReachable.rawValue):
        isAvailable = false;
        break;
    case (ReachableViaWiFi.rawValue):
        isAvailable = true;
        break;
    case (ReachableViaWWAN.rawValue):
        isAvailable = true;
        break;
    default:
        isAvailable = false;
        break;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use like this

```
do {
    let reachability: Reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

     switch reachability.currentReachabilityStatus{
     case .ReachableViaWiFi:
         print("Connected With wifi")
     case .ReachableViaWWAN:
         print("Connected With Cellular network(3G/4G)")
     case .NotReachable:
         print("Not Connected")
     }
}
catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```