# popup alert when Reachability connection is lost during using the app (IOS xcode swift)

Tags: ios, swift, alert, reachability

I am a beginner of IOS app development and would like to "popup alert when Reachability connection is lost during using the app  (IOS xcode swift)",
but I only get popup alert when starting the my app. There is not alert popup during using my app when internet connection lost. Please kindly help, thanks!

What I did:
1) creat a Reachability.swift file and worte

```
import Foundation

public class Reachability {

class func isConnectedToNetwork()->Bool{

    var Status:Bool = false

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10.0        

    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            Status = true
        }
    }

    return Status
 }
 }
```

2) edit the **ViewController.swift** file as below

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

//ViewDidLoad method
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        println("Internet connection OK")
    } else {
        println("Internet connection FAILED")
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection",
                                message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", 
                                delegate: nil, 
                                cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        alert.show()

    }
    var URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")

    WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928826/using-apples-reachability-class-in-swift

Comment: Why the if-else condition repeated twice? I guess it is a typing mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [Reachabilty](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) class, add it in your project and do the following in your `viewController`

```
let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Reachable via WiFi", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

} 
else {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Reachable via Cellular", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Not Reachable", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

reachability.startNotifier()
```

Comment: thanks, but I am really a beginner, please kindly guide me step by step how to do it.

Comment: 1.)add reachability.swift file into your project.  2)and paste above code either in your viewDidLoad method. or applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. and run the code

Comment: thank you very much! I follow your answer and it works 99%. I put your viewDidLoad method of ViewController.

Comment: The only problem now is that there is no alert when starting the app without internet connection. Can you help ?

Comment: instead of println put your alert code bro. And UIAlertView is depricated in iOS8. use UIAlertController

Comment: yes, i did. Thats why it shows alert, if the app started and then connection fail. But if no connection now and start the app, there is no alert. Code "         reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in

            println("Not reachable")

            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

            alert.show()

        }

Comment: use self.presentviewController in viewDidLoad

Comment: No error now, but same as before. There is no alert when starting the app without internet connection.

Comment: dispatch_async is exist in my project, I search it on the web and it is too complicate for me to understand at the moment, i need time to investegate it.