# Show Alert if no Network Connection

Tags: swift

How can you notify the user that there is no network connection with swift 3. I have tried a bunch of solutions and none of them have worked so far. I am not looking for the speed of the network connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the network speed using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635804/how-to-check-the-network-speed-using-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popup alert when Reachability connection is lost during using the app (IOS xcode swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400192/popup-alert-when-reachability-connection-is-lost-during-using-the-app-ios-xcode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of resources showing how to check the Internet connection. E.g., from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40148883/7113238).

```
    func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
    {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }

    func showAlert() {
        if !isInternetAvailable() {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "The Internet is not available", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

You need to import:

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration
```

Comment: You can call `showAlert()` from `viewDidLoad()` fort testing.

Comment: Anywhere, it's up to your design. If you are in a ViewController and want to test then put it there.

Comment: I put it in view controller and nothing happpened

Comment: 1. Call `showAlert()` in `viewDidLoad`? 2. Turn off the Internet? 3. Debug to see if the code is running correctly?

Comment: Did 1 and 2 but not three