# Is it possible to check if WiFi is connected but there is no internet connection in Swift using Reachability?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, reachability-swift

I don't know if this is possible but here's my question -

- When the WiFi is connected & the internet is **ON** then **Yellow Light** glows on Router
- When the WiFi is connected & the Internet is **OFF** then **Red Light** glows on Router

So is it possible to distinguish the 2nd case or is it just the same as when Internet is not reachable?

I am using https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Complete code can be found https://github.com/deadcoder0904/net-alert

Its basically in just [one file](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/net-alert/blob/master/Net%20Alert/AppDelegate.swift)

Relevant code -

```
let reachability = Reachability()!

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
    if reachability.connection == .wifi {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
            self.setStatusIcon(color: "green")
    } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
            self.setStatusIcon(color: "yellow")
    }
}

reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in
    print("Not reachable")
    self.setStatusIcon(color: "red")
}

do {
    try reachability.startNotifier()
} catch {
    print("Unable to start notifier")
    self.setStatusIcon(color: "yellow")
}
```

where `setStatusIcon()` sets the status icon according to the color

I want to know when internet is not reachable but WiFi is connected in Swift?

Comment: Using the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild, you could run `ping 8.8.8.8`, for example, and see if you get an answer. Getting an answer would mean there is Internet.
Just in case Reachability does not offer a better way.

Comment: Oops why didn't I think of that. Thanks @regina_fallangi I'll update my code to see if it works

Comment: It'd work everywhere but China, I believe. Do answer your own question if it works, it's definitely interesting to see if it works.

Comment: Yes true. I read some Apple website will work in China as well. Finding that answer so I can use that website instead of Google & sure I will answer the question. I always do :)

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938650/ios-detect-3g-or-wifi

Comment: @dniswhite I have the same code in swift. its just there is no case of Wifi Connected but no internet :(

Comment: @dniswhite that question is only to see if there is connection to the wifi and the solution is `Reachability`, which OP is already using. Please read the question better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713449/using-apples-reachability-to-check-remote-server-reachability-in-swift

Comment: Thanks @Augie so I think I can't use Reachability for that. I have to actually ping the server to see if the server is online :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

As Augie suggested, its not possible to do it with Reachability as it just checks if the WiFi or Cellular is reachable or not.

So I had to ping a website to check if it is online or not.

If I get a 200 response from it then its connected.

But if I don't get a 200, then even though WiFi is connected but there is no internet.

I didn't know how to Ping properly so I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52512244/6141587) where I got [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52512557/6141587)

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/net-alert